# Does Swagger/RAML (or any similar REST API spec) supports REST asynchronous client callbacks?

Tags: rest, asynchronous, swagger, raml

I want to use REST async client callback, meaning the server is causing a callback operation to be invoked on the client side when a response is ready (see [Jersey's 'Asynchronous Services and Clients'](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/async.html) to get what I mean)

Can I express this in Swagger/RAML/anything similar, and enjoy the relevant server/client code generation, documentation generation etc.? Can you point to relevant examples/resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OAS (formerly Swagger) considered it:
https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/716
https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/737
and even merged the [callback feature](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/pull/763) and landed in OAS 3.0.
But the tools I used doesn't seems to support the addition at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout out [Async API](https://www.asyncapi.com)

Quoting from https://www.asyncapi.com/v1/guide/

> AsyncAPI provides a specification that allows you to define Message-Driven APIs in a machine-readable format. It’s protocol-agnostic, so you can use it for APIs that work over MQTT, AMQP, WebSockets, STOMP, etc. The spec is very similar to OpenAPI/Swagger so, if you’re familiar with them, AsyncAPI should be easy for you.

Repo: https://github.com/asyncapi/asyncapi

Async API supports

- Documentation Generation : https://www.asyncapi.com/v1/tooling/docgens.html
- Code Generation (Java, Node.js): https://www.asyncapi.com/v1/tooling/codegens.html

---

There is also Swagger **Callback** feature ( [documentation for the callback feature.](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/callbacks/) )

Answer (score 0):

That comes with OAS 3.0 as far as I remember. So there isn't a tool which supports this feature yet.